# Lua Torch equivalent of np.where()?

Tags: numpy, lua, torch

I have a `ByteTensor` and want to grab the indices where there is a `1`. In numpy, I could do something like

```
a = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
return np.where(a)
```

which would return `(array([0, 2, 4]),)`. Is this functionality defined in Torch?

(In my particular case, I want to use these indices to index into several different Tensor objects, but it'd be nice to know how to do this in general.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [torch.nonzero](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#longtensor-nonzerotensor), e.g.:

```
> a = torch.ByteTensor{1,0,1,0,1}
> print(torch.nonzero(a))                                                                                         
 1                                                                                                                  
 3                                                                                                                  
 5                                                                                                                  
[torch.LongTensor of size 3x1]
```

If you really need to find the 1-s only you can chain a logical operator:

```
> a = torch.ByteTensor{1,2,1,6,1}
> a:eq(1):nonzero()
```